# How to set Proxy Setting only for HTTP using c#

Tags: c#, proxy, registry

[image: Proxy Setting]

I would like to set the Proxy server setting only for HTTP request and not for other secure protocols as shown in the picture. But, when I use this code,

```
        const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
        const string subkey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
        const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyServer", proxyhost + ":"+ port.ToString());
        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyEnable", 1 );
```

this set the Proxy setting for all the protocols. So help me in setting the proxy setting only for HTTP protocol.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was so simple, just include the http= to the Proxy server so the system can understand that only Proxy is enabled for http protocol not for other protocols.

```
        proxyhost = "http=" + proxyhost + ":"+ port.ToString();
        const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
        const string subkey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
        const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;

        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyServer", proxyhost);
        Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ProxyEnable", proxyEnabled ? 1 : 0);
```